# Setting Kivy in Pycharm (Mac)

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I am a Mac-based Pycharm Python developer. It seems like I can't use Pycharm to develop using the Kivy framework because there is no official support.

While choosing the path: /usr/local/bin/kivy as the interpreter path, 
an error message: Invalid python interpreter name{0} appears.

How can I use Kivy in Pycharm?

Answer (score 3):

Did you install kivy in your system from the zip, using the setup.py file in it?. I had a similar problem, which was because I hadn't installed it properly and using it in portable mode.

Answer (score 2):

I updated the wiki at https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE's#setting-up-kivy-with-pycharm-4-on-osx

It's just setting some environment variables.